# What is the appropriate means of bias field in image processing?

Tags: image-processing

I want to do image segmentation. In (Li, C. et al, 2011) article about A Level Set Method for Image Segmentation I saw that the authors use bias field estimation. I searched a lot but I couldn't understand the meaning of bias field...What is the appropriate mean of bias field?

Comment: Can you provide a full citation to the article you are referring to?  (authors, where published, and preferably a link to a PDF if one is freely available)  When you write "outer" do you mean "authors"?  What do you mean by "appropriate means"?  What have you tried, and what research have you done already?

Comment: excuse me :)  I mean authors. this article is in this link http://www.imagecomputing.org/~cmli/paper/levelset_segmentation_biasCorrection.pdf  ....I can't understand the bias field in this article. if I can't speak english well I should said excuse me again.

Comment: No need to apologize about your English; just trying to help you improve the question.  Anyway, please edit the question with all relevant information/clarifications.  Comments exist only to help you improve the question -- people shouldn't have to read the comments to understand your question.

Comment: ok. thanks. in this question I just want to know what is a bias field in image processing. I think it is all the things that I want

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bias field is magnetic based inhomogenity in results of MRI, which comes from magnetic settings, patient position etc.
This term has no standard definition in terms of image processing.
Essentialy this is smooth, low frequency, gradiented signal, which covers valuable data.
In terms of MRI this is just artifact and very often when somebody says that image will be preprocessed or will get rid of artifacts, bias field is included (naming it simply - noise from equipement).